# Deleted files won't go away

Tags: css, cache

I have a file that's auto generated by my theme. It's called design_storename.css

There are a few changes that weren't updating on my site, so I deleted that file, changed another setting and it regenerated. The old file is still the one loading, and I can't figure out why.

I've cleaned and flushed the caches, regenerated the file a half dozen times, ran setup:di:compile, reindexed, ran redis-cli flushall, cleared the Varnish cache, disabled the varnish cache, and that stubborn file keeps loading.

What can I do to make it go away and be replaced with the new one?

Thanks

Comment: design_storename.css sounds like you are using a purchased theme 99% of the time this css file is usually generated by the admin system configuration. can you provide the path to the file or give us an idea of the theme you are using

Comment: It's being generated by the Porto theme. The url is https://staging.example.com/media/porto/configed_css/design_sfsupplies.css and even when I delete the file and have it regenerated, the old one still comes up

Comment: ahhh good old porto, if you delete this file pub/media/porto/configed_css/design_sfsupplies.css, then go to Porto - Design Panel > Save Config this should regenerate this file.

Comment: I did that multiple times. The file generates just fine, but when I access that url, all I see is a cached file. Even if I delete the file from the server completely, flush all caches and even restart the server, the same old file is still the one that shows up

Comment: If you have varnish/redis/fastly or cloudflare you may need to flush these also

Comment: Varnish is disabled and I flushed Redis, but the server guys manage cloudflare, I think those caches are off, but I'll check

Comment: Sounds like a cache issue, iv seen this with cloud flare a few times.

Comment: Cloudflare was the issue. Thank you @Dava Gordon. Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your issue we have have come to the conclusion that the reason for the file not changing is down to cache. this is a common issue when using 3rd party caching platforms

**Suppliers Checked**

- [Fastly](https://explore.fastly.com/)
- [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/)
- [Redis](https://redis.io/)
- [Cloudflair](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/)